# How to translate Validation field name in magento 2

Tags: magento2, validation

how to translate the field name in magento 2
that comes in %
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just go-to that input field and add a custom attribute "data-msg-required"

data-msg-(validator name)

```
<input name="qty" id="qty" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate='{"required":true}' data-msg-required="Please select size."/>
```